# Algorithm forward_list is sorted?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, forward-list

I have some difficulties in C++11. I would like to create function `isSorted` which return true if my `std::forward_list` is sorted, and false if not.

I have imagined code like this:

```
template<class T>
bool estTriee(forward_list<T>& list) {
        typename forward_list<T>::iterator it;
        it = list.begin();

        while(it != list.end() &&  *it <= *next(it, 1)) {
            it++;
        }

        return it == list.end();
}
```

But gcc return me a segmentation fault surrounding the while line.

Answer (score 7):

Your code will fail if the iterator reaches the *last element* in the list. When that happens `std::next(it)` is equal to `list.end()` and it's an error to dereference an `end()` iterator (causing a segfault in this case).

My suggestion is to use the [`std::is_sorted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) algorithm in the standard library. It's already written, debugged, and does what you want.

```
template<class T>
bool estTriee(const std::forward_list<T>& list) {
    return std::is_sorted(list.begin(), list.end());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I will try this but I thnink it's will work well